# RegEx Help. Using lookaround to insert periods inbetween spaced digits, but only if the digit isn't at the very end of a word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

Examples:

```
RP Distort2 1 0 0b.exe
AFakeFilename4 5 0 2 SEP2 5 63 8
A4 5 8 7 6 COM99 6 4 4 1
```

Should become:

```
RP Distort2 1.0.0b.exe
AFakeFilename4 5.0.2 SEP2 5.63.8
A4 5.8.7.6 COM99 6.4.4.1
```

My current expression is:

```
(?<=\d) (?=\d)

Replacement: .
```

Right now my expression only partially works. It inserts periods between *all* spaced digits. I.E: `RP Distort2 1 0 0b.exe` becomes `RP Distort2.1.0.0b.exe` when it should be `RP Distort2 1.0.0b.exe`

I am not a RegEx wizard so this has me kind of stumped. I also got my expression from another site - I know it's using lookaround but I don't exactly understand the syntax of lookaround.

I'm using this expression in [den4b Renamer (beta3)](https://www.den4b.com/changelogs/renamer) which now supports lookaround fully.

How can I modify my expression to achieve what I need here?

Any help at all would be enormously appreciated.

Edit:

I also want to add an additional condition. If a digit is immediately after a single `v` I.E: `TestSoftware v1 5 5`, this should not count as "at the end of a word" (an exception) and the result should be `TestSoftware v1.5.5`.

Comment: Lookarounds do not seem to be implemented, you could run for example this pattern twice `\b(v?\d+) (\d)` and replace with `$1.$2`

Comment: @Jay Have you tried https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/?  I have no idea as to the strength of it's regex capabilities, just throwing it out there as one i have used in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my commemt to an answer for future readers.

Lookarounds do not seem to be implemented, you could run for example this pattern twice:

```
\b(v?\d+) (\d)
```

In the replacement use `$1.$2`

Answer (score 0):

This would do the substitutions you want from the example strings you have in your question

Match and capture:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=\sv))(\d+)\s(?=\d)
```

Substitution:

```
$1.
```

- `(?:` - start of non-capturing group

  - `(?<=\s)` - positive lookbehind for a whitespace
  - `|` - OR
  - `(?<=\sv)` - positive lookbehind for a whitespace + `v`
- `)` - end of non-capturing group
- `(\d+)\s` - match and capture 1 or more digits followed by a whitespace
- `(?=\d)` - positive lookahead for a digit

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SjPyHs/1)

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately the expression is throwing an error in my application. I'm using Den4b renamer. The error is: `TRegExpr compile: lookaround brackets must be at the very beginning/ending (pos 4)`

Not sure how to modify the expression so it works. I really appreciate the help though.

Comment: @Jay That's unfortunate. Do they state which regex engine they use at _Den4b renamer_? Is it any of those available at https://regex101.com ? If so, i could give it a try using that engine. If you can't find the information, perhaps you could ask them which of those engines listed at regex101 that is closest to their engine (if any)? If you get that info, just ping me here and I'll try to see if I can update the answer.

Comment: I do not know what engine they use unfortunately. :( I just posted on their forum to find out. I'll get back to you when I know more details of their implementation.

Comment: I kind of found a workaround with the program. I just added another regex rule below: 
`([a-uw-z]\d)(\.)(\d)` Replace: `$1 $3` (Non case sensitive)

This simply removes trailing periods after numbers that occur immediately after any letter for the exception of `v`. So it basically just "cleans up" the previous process. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\b\d+\K (?=\d)` if your regex supports the \K feature, what I call the poor man's variable lookbehind.   It discards the entire match to that point.

Regex101 on PCRE regex,
[image]

Comment: Nice, although the exception for `v` that should make `TestSoftware v1 5 5` into `TestSoftware v1.5.5` won't work.

Comment: Unfortunately the app doesn't support \K. Getting `TRegExpr compile unknown meta-character: \K (pos 6)`

Comment: Kind of a brain-dead regex flavor.  No variable-length lookbehind, no embedded lookbehind (or lookahead), no \K match discard...

Comment: Yeah no kidding :( I'm going to plead with the developer to expand its regex functionality. I will say though, it's the best bulk renamer on the market for windows. It's extremely powerful despite the poor-man's regex implementation. Highly recommend it.